# How to open an item in Device Manager without a mouse?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, device-manager

We have a Windows 10 system.  The USB mouse's left click isn't working (the right click works, and I'm not sure about the wheel.  The pointer is fine).  To try to fix this, I figured out how to get into Device Manager, and it looks like I need to open up the "Mice and pointing devices" item so that I can select the device.  I can highlight the "Mice and pointing devices" line, but I can't figure out how to open it.  I've provided a picture of what I *want* to get at (from a different computer, and of course the actual mouse device would be different).

[image: Device Manager menu]

Are there any keyboard sequences for opening up the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the left <kbd>←</kbd> and right <kbd>→</kbd>  arrow keys you can close and open the submenu respectively.

Comment: Use the tab key to get to the list if you get stuck before Nordlys' suggestion.

Comment: Thanks--hope this helps someone else.  If I Google "mouse left click doesn't work" or something, there are sites which appear to have good answers but tell you to open this menu without giving you any idea how.  Grrr...  P.S. In my case, I was able to find another mouse and determine that the problem was with the first mouse itself and not the drivers.

Comment: For those with driver problems(or no option to try another mouse): the `Enter` key is equivalent to the left click and the `Menu` key (situated between right `Win`and right `CTRL` key) the equivalent for the right click.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>M</kbd> to go to mouse options, arrow key to choose the mouse option you want to delete or enable, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> then arrow key up/down to the option then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).